# Eclipse maven after compile cannot see target/classes folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After doing `mvn clean compile install` i can not see any files in target/classes folder in eclipse. But when i have a look in filesystem the folder is there with compiled classes files inside. But when i start a unit test, it says "there is no target/classes folder"

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution was: Right click project -> properties -> build path -> Source tab -> "Allow output folders for source folders" and add the output folder target/classes explicit to each source folder. This works for me and after adding all folders, project could be compiled and executed

Comment: Yes, but for some reason this flag keeps getting reset to checked after a maven update (alt-F5).  Any idea what in the pom is telling Eclipse to do that?

Comment: @Marc This flag is stored in the `.classpath` in the project. I am seeing the same behaviour as you. Even when I manually edit this file to try and force this setting, it still does not take. :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I noticed `target\test-classes` dir files okay but not `target\classes`. From effective pom I copied relevant part and provided `target\test-classes` instead. Now, at least I got a full jar snapshot instead of an empty one !

Comment: Uncheck "Allow output folders for source folders" and check and click apply. This work for me. Thanks Dennis...

Comment: When you change your pom.xml at some point in the future, eclipse will update its .project and .classpath files and you will lose your changes to the build path.

Answer (score 6):

From my experience it would seam that Eclipse does not monitor the file system for changes. So  if you created your classes the you manually ran maven from command line, I suspect you'd have to right click your project in Eclipse (from the Navigator for example), and click refresh, and only after this you'll see the new files.

You could also install the [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) and the [m2-wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) maven plugins for Eclipse, and run your build process from inside Eclipse which should detect all the changes on the file system.

Comment: Thx for the nice advises @Grove. I have found the solution. Solution was: Right click project -> properties -> build path -> Source tab -> "Allow output folders for source folders" and add the output folder target/classes explicit to each source folder. This works for me and after adding all folders, project could be compiled and executed.

Comment: Cool, glad I could be of some help. Also, if none of the proposed answers are correct, you can post your own solution and select it as the right answer to the question. It does not necessarily have to be someone else's response every time. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling

When enabled, any changes made by external editors will be automatically discovered by the Workbench.